# What are the pros and cons of using Dublin Core meta tags?

Tags: html, meta-tags, dublin-core

This is an open question on why, how, or when to use or not use Dublin Core meta tags.

For example, `<meta name="DC.title" content="Title of my Webpage" />`. Should this be used in addition to or instead of the `<title>` meta tag?

Does a certain approach help or hinder SEO? Does adding a lot of "description" to a page outweigh the added code bloat to the page?

Answer (score 4):

Dublin Core might be useful to someone scanning your site and cataloging what's on it, but Google is more likely to use microformats to verify breadcrumbs, product listings, pricing or article structure. They're moving from their rich snippets to http://www.schema.org/ markup.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell they have no SEO value. The search engines already disregard standard meta description and keyword tags for ranking purposes and the `<title>` tag is sufficient so a meta tag with the same info is redundant. I wouldn't bother with these until there is a practical use for them.

Comment: Not the description meta. Unless something changed recently they still use that.