# Is there any point to embedding Dublin Core in a broad, public web site?

Tags: meta-tags, dublin-core

I'm adding JSON-LD / schema.org to a couple apps with a million pages (legal publishing).

I've had Dublin Core embedded in the pages for years, but don't know of any benefits I've received from having these 12 or so `meta` tags. There's definitely a maintenance cost (and secondarily byte count). Just looking at the tags, I can see I need to put in more time to verify I'm using them correctly, etc.

I've never heard or detected any benefit from having them: SEO, inter-connectivity, or otherwise. On the other hand, I've seen the direct benefits of using JSON-LD / schema.org in my pages: better semantic search result presentations, and custom tailored metadata about my content.

It seems that Dublin Core is superfluous and costly without benefits in my situation. (?)

Comment: Closely related (if not duplicate): [What are the pros and cons of using Dublin Core meta tags?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/23108/17633)

Comment: I personally never implement any meta data or any markup to make my pages more machine comprehensible without first knowing who is going to consume it and what benefit that will get me.     I have only implemented a handful that Google uses to enhance the display of my site in the search results.